# Name-Dependent Plugin Topics

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to simulate multiple (2) AR.Drone Parrot quatrotors in gazebo.  I'm using the [tum_simulator](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator) package, which in turn presents the same interface as the [ardrone_autonomy](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy) driver for the real-world drones.  I can spawn a single drone without error, and fly it around programmatically with roscpp.  I can also spawn multiple drones without error by duplicating the launch code and surrounding it with `<group ns="drone{0,1}">` tags.  After manipulating some `tf` parameters, the drones spawn without error.

The simulator subscribes to properly namespaced topics, for the most part.  For example, instead of `/cmd_vel`, there are now two topics `/drone0/cmd_vel` and `/drone1/cmd_vel`.  However, topics to control takeoff and landing are hardcoded in a gazebo plugin as `/ardrone/{takeoff,landing,reset}`, and `rxgraph` shows that these topics are not duplicated between namespaces, they remain prefixed only by `/ardrone`.

How is it possible to have the plugin offer namespaced topics that are linked up to each drone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/896/name-dependent-plugin-topics/) by [David Millard](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/158/david-millard/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Figured it out: tum_simulator hardcodes some paths as absolute.  Removing the leading '/' from relevant topics (`/ardrone/takeoff`, `/ardrone/land`, `/ardrone/reset`, etc) in the `cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins` package fixed it up.

---

Originally posted by [David Millard](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/158/david-millard/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Millard](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/158/david-millard/) on 2020-12-02**:
I received an email about this answer recently over confusion on what to change. The relevant values are in https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator/blob/master/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/quadrotor_state_controller.cpp.

I don't believe that the package is taking pull requests since 2014, and I'm not aware of an active fork to submit a patch to.